# How to loop this JSON data into a table?

Tags: javascript, html, pug, template-engine

I have this json data:

```
{
    "particles": {
        "name": "particles",
        "values": [
            ["35.5", 1466588408869],
            ["35.5", 1466589538531],
            ["45.5", 1466589577084]
        ]
    },
    "timestamps": {
        "name": "timestamps",
        "values": [
            ["144500", 1466588408870],
            ["144500", 1466589538531],
            ["144500", 1466589577084]
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I loop it into table below?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>particles</th>
    <th>timestamps</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>35.5</td>
    <td>144500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>35.5</td>
    <td>144500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>45.5</td>
    <td>144500</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My attempt:

```
div.table-responsive
    table.table.table-hover.table-bordered
        thead
            tr
                each variable, i in dataset.data
                    if variable.name
                        th.text-center #{variable.name}
        tbody
            tr
                each variable, i in dataset.data
                    if variable.values
                        td
                            each value, i in variable.values
                                p=  value[0]
```

Result (not good):

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="text-center">particles</th>
                <th class="text-center">timestamps</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><p>35.5</p><p>35.5</p><p>45.5</p></td>
          <td><p>144500</p><p>144500</p><p>144500</p></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can we solve it with jquery ?

Comment: maybe. why not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's dirty but here maybe a beginning of an answer... It's better than nothing.

You can impregnate yourself from this:

```js
var data = {
    "particles": {
        "name": "particles",
        "values": [
            ["35.5", 1466588408869],
            ["35.5", 1466589538531],
            ["45.5", 1466589577084]
        ]
    },
    "timestamps": {
        "name": "timestamps",
        "values": [
            ["144500", 1466588408870],
            ["144500", 1466589538531],
            ["144500", 1466589577084]
        ]
    }
};

var titles = [];
var append = "";

$.each(data, function(i, e) {
  titles.push(e.name);
});

append += "<tr>";
$.each(titles, function(i, title) {
  append += "<th>" + title + "</th>";
});
append += "</tr>";

$.each(data[titles[0]].values, function(i, e) {
  append += "<tr>";
  $.each(titles, function(o, title) {
    append += "<td>" + data[title].values[i][0] + "</td>";
  });
  append += "</tr>";
});

$("#result").append(append);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="result"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have followed the pattern of your answer and wrote the jade solution. see my answer below. Thank!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro in Javascript/JQuery but i make my own solution, of course there is better way to do it, but with my answer and the other answer, maybe you can make your own solution.

There is mine :

```
var obj = {
    "particles": {
        "name": "particles",
        "values": [
            ["35.5", 1466588408869],
            ["35.5", 1466589538531],
            ["45.5", 1466589577084]
        ]
    },
    "timestamps": {
        "name": "timestamps",
        "values": [
            ["144500", 1466588408870],
            ["144500", 1466589538531],
            ["144500", 1466589577084]
        ]
    }
}

var table_length = 0;
var y = {};
for (var i in obj) {
   y = obj[i];
   break;
}

table_length = y.values.length+1;

for (var j=0 ; j < table_length; j++) {
$("table").append("<tr></tr>");
}

for (var i in obj) {
   $("table tr:first").append("<th>"+obj[i].name+"</th>");
   var x = 1;
   for (var j in obj[i].values) {
      $('table tr').eq(x).append("<td>"+obj[i].values[j][0]+"</td>");
      x++;
   }
}
```

LIVE DEMO [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgsLqh5g/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have followed the pattern of your answer and wrote the jade solution. see my answer below. Thank!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answer in Jase:

```
table.table.table-hover.table-bordered
    thead
        tr
            each variable, i in dataset.data
                if variable.name
                    th.text-center #{variable.name}
    tbody
        - var data = dataset.data;
        - var titles = [];
        - for (var property in data) titles.push(property)

        =JSON.stringify(data)

        each value, i in data[titles[0]].values
            tr
                each title, x in titles
                    td= data[title].values[i][0]
```

What the hell!